# Getting the error in GitLab while running the CI/CD

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gitlab, cicd

Getting the below error that session not created while running the CI/CD for selenium with java for automation testing.

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:

The code should be execute into the browser and give the test result.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE]. Without seeing some code, we are not able to help.